# "Specularità" è italiano?

Tags: word-choice

Mi riferisco a la proprietà che esiste tra A e B quando l'uno è speculare all'altro.

Non ho un vocaboolario cartaceo con me, ma

- ho il vago ricordo di aver cercato e *non* trovato questa parola sul [Devoto-Oli](https://s.sbito.it/images/70/70e84840-97ff-4ab2-90fe-ff867bb23c08.jpg)
- [Treccani.it](https://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/ricerca/specularit%C3%A0/) sembra non contemplarlo.

L'ho trovato [qui](https://dizionario.internazionale.it/parola/specularita), ma non conosco questa fonte.

Comment: Se non fosse nei dizionari, sarebbe comunque italiano, perché è formato correttamente dall'aggettivo *speculare*.

Comment: Scusa, @egreg, ma allora posso dire che _fradicità_ è italiano perché è formato dall'aggettivo _fradicio_? O forse no perché l'ho formato non **correttamente**?

Comment: Perché no? L'importante è che se ne possa ricavare un significato sensato.

Comment: _Perché no?_ No, @egreg, non è che io sia contrario. Anzi, mio nipote si è inventato _freddaia_ estrapolandolo da _caldaia_, e io lo proporrei pure come sinonimo più specifico di _condizionatore_. E _petaloso_ mi piace. Però non capisco perché non dovrei voler usare _speculanza_ e _importantità_ invece di _specularità_ e _importanza_. Il tuo commento mi fa pensare dovrei accettarli tutti e quattro, ma penso non sia ciò che intendi.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Certo che *specularità* è italiano.

La fonte cui ti riferisci è il *Nuovo Vocabolario di base della lingua italiana* di Tullio De Mauro, pubblicato online da *Internazionale*

https://www.internazionale.it/opinione/tullio-de-mauro/2016/12/23/il-nuovo-vocabolario-di-base-della-lingua-italiana

Tullio De Mauro è stato uno dei maggiori e più autorevoli linguisti italiani, probabilmente il più famoso.

https://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/tullio-de-mauro_%28Enciclopedia-Italiana%29/

https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tullio_De_Mauro

Comment: Non che ce ne sia bisogno ma confermo con convinzione quello che spiega BakerStreet su Tullio De Mauro e sul dizionario da lui curato. Aggiungo per puro interesse statistico che anche su un'edizione più recente del Devoto-Oli è assente “specularità”, che invece è presente sullo Zingarelli (“caratteristica di ciò che è speculare; fig. simmetria, corrispondenza”).

Comment: Certo, il fatto è che i vocabolari non  possono contenere tutto per motivi di spazio, devono fare delle scelte, non è che escludono alcuni termini perché pensano che non siano italiano. Se un termine  sta in De mauro, o nel Devoto-Oli, o nello Zingarelli o in genere in vocabolari di prestigio, si può stare certi che è italiano anche se non compare in altri dizionari.